# Passing Labels from PHP to Chart.js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, chart.js

I'm trying to pass a list of names into the labels section of a Chart.js chart which I'm retrieving from a database with PHP.

In my controller I do

```
json_encode(array_pluck($var->toArray(), 'name'));
```

which returns:

```
"["name1","name2","name3","name4","name5","name6"]"
```

In the view, I have:

```
labels: {{ $var }},
```

and when I view the source, I can see

```
&quot;name1&quot;,&quot;name2&quot;,&quot;name3&quot;,&quot;name4&quot;,&quot;name5&quot;,&quot;name6&quot;
```

This is causing the chart to fail as it's expecting:

```
'name1','name2','name3','name4','name5','name6'
```

I've tried various things such as `html_entity_decode`, `json_decode` and `htmlspecialchars_decode` but not of them seem to do anything.

Comment: Have you tried using {!! $assets_by_department_departments !!} - this should prevent the html for being encoded.

Comment: I knew it would be something simple! Thanks man, that got it working.

Comment: Great you got it working - I'll just add it as an answer.

Comment: Approved the answer, thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `{!! $assets_by_department_departments !!}` - This will prevent Blade from escaping the data.

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#displaying-data for further details :)